# How to obtain if user likes page or not with API 3.0?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

All what I found is related to old API not 3.0 :\ I need to determine that before an application will display proper message.

Comment: Is there any way to get this done without Permission Request pop-up window? I'm new to Facebook API but have PHP knowledge. I have try to use that but doesn't work:

    $user       = $facebook->getUser();

    $created_time = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid= '.$user.' AND page_id = 111127675620841'));

Comment: is your applications is loaded *inside* the page as page tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Answer (score 0):

Your app will need to request the **user_likes** permission in order to do this.

Then, you can do the following using the JavaScript SDK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if(response.authResponse) {
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) {
          likes = response.data;
          for(x in likes) {
            page_id = likes[x].id;
            page_name = likes[x].name;
            // check if user is a fan of Coca-Cola
            if(page_id == '40796308305') {
                alert('You like the page:\n ' + page_name);
            }
          }
        }, {access_token: token});
    }
});
</script>
```

Or the following, using the PHP SDK:

```
<?php
$likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
foreach($likes[data] as $like) {
    if(array_key_exists('id', $like)) {
        $page_id = $like['id'];
        $page_name = $like['name'];
        // check if user is a fan of Coca-Cola
        if($page_id == '40796308305') {
            print 'You like the page: ' . $page_name;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The only way to do it is with permissions. Facebook won't allow you to access that data otherwise.

Comment: So how others do without permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a Facebook fan page, Facebook has a post on how to do this with your [iframe page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/).  You need to decode the signed_request http post parameter that gets sent to your site.  This page shows you [how to decode it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

http://fatalweb.com/articles/how+to+check+if+user+has+liked+facebook+fanpage-24.htm